# How to run perft with Stockfish in the terminal on a macbook?

Tags: engines, software, stockfish, programming

I just got a Macbook and I'm attempting to build a chess engine, so I want to run the perft function on Stockfish to compare my perft results. When I was on PC, I was able to download the engine from the website and run the perft function fine, but I can't figure out how to do it on mac. I tried downloading Stockfish with Homebrew which apparently worked but when I tried the `./stockfish` command to run t it outputted this error: `zsh: no such file or directory: ./stockfish`. Can anyone provide complete steps to do this? Or if there's any alternative that has a feature equivalent to what Stockfish's perft does that would be good too.

Comment: what is the executable called? this question is more suited for unix or apple stack exchange.

Comment: @qwr I wasn't sure where to post this but I decided to put it here because I figured that more people would know how to solve this in case it was a Stockfish-related problem and not purely a Unix problem. The executable in the src folder is called stockfish if that's what you're asking. I tried opening Stockfish by clicking on the executable icon and I got a `zsh: illegal hardware instruction` error in the terminal window that opened

Comment: which MacBook are you using? You need to get a binary that matches your hardware. If it's designed for M1 chip then you need to get that binary version.

Comment: @qwr I'm on a 2023 14 inch pro with an m2 chip. So do I need a different version of Stockfish?

Comment: you installed through homebrew? that means it should be in your PATH right? what happens if you try `stockfish` without ./

Comment: I don't use homebrew but it should've picked the right version for your hardware and OS.

Comment: @qwr Yeah just doing `stockfish` did the trick, thanks. Apologies for the off-topic question

Comment: @wdk23 shouldn't you mark the question as solved?

Comment: @emdio I'm new to stack exchange, so correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as my knowledge of this site goes I can't because the responses were comments and not answers

Comment: @wdk23 I wasn't aware of that. In any case it seems you can answer your own question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer So why not just do it -with proper credit- and mark it as answered?

Comment: @emdio sounds good, I'll do that

Comment: "with proper credit"

Comment: @qwr sorry about that, how do I tag you in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I downloaded stockfish through homebrew and was able to run it on the terminal with the command `stockfish`. All other commands are the same.

Credit: @qwr in the comments